# Publish WinRT application with SharpCompress library

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, sharpcompress

The current SharpCompress.WindowsStore.dll library published on Nuget is build in Debug mode. I got this error from the Windows Store App Certification Kit.

**Error Found**: The debug configuration test detected the following errors:
The binary SharpCompress.WindowsStore.dll is built in debug mode.

Is there any way to have/compile the SharpCompress lib in Release Mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd rebuild it in release mode.

What, you didn't think about that?

[It's on NuGet, right?](http://www.nuget.org/packages/sharpcompress/)  NuGet packages often list a project site.  So looking at the page I can see the link points [right over here.](https://github.com/adamhathcock/sharpcompress)  That's on GitHub.  That's where source lives.

You can either fork it (which there isn't really a point, since you don't want to develop it), clone it (aka use a Git tool such as GitHub for Windows) to your local machine, [or just download the latest code in a zip file](https://github.com/adamhathcock/sharpcompress/archive/master.zip).

From there you can build in release mode and away you go.  May not be just that easy, as there might be some dependencies or such that need resolving.  Now off you go.

Comment: I did that and i cloned the repository i removed the project key because they were blocked by a password. But after that removal i got this error:   Unable to get MD5 checksum for the key file "..\SharpCompress\SharpCompress.pfx". Could not find file '..\SharpCompress\SharpCompress.pfx'. SharpCompress.Test

Comment: Anyway i unloaded the test project and i got my SharpCompress.WindowsStore.dll compiled in Release mode. Thx